# Unable to limit the edit of the "amount" field up to 2 decimal places on "Price List Item" entity in MS CRM 365

Tags: dynamics-crm

On "Price List Item" entity, we have an "amount" field of type currency. We require limiting the user to enter the amount in that field up to 2 decimal places only. Example, if the user wishes to enter 100.100 then he should not be able to write only up to 2 decimal places ie. **100.10**[Image shows the invalid value allowed to enter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7oeH.png)

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible without doing something unsupported. You can attach to the key press event of a *text* field, but not any other type of field.

If you wish to follow a dark and dangerous path, aka the unsupported route (and note that I do not advise this), you can still attach to the underlying inputs. Using something like this in jquery for example:

```js
function onload()  
{  
  $("#amount_i").keypress(...);    
}
```

But that's a rabbit hole I shall not venture down any further. In regard to CRM I'm very much a blue pill kind of guy.

Comment: As per the below link, it seems like the event "addOnKeyPress" is only supported for "Single line of Text field" in CRM. Please suggest is it also working for a "Currency" type field?https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/198412

Comment: You're correct. It doesn't work on currency fields. So I will update my answer to reflect this (i.e. it's not possible without doing something unsupported)

Answer (score 0):

You can *hide* the field and insert a HTML webresource mimicking the field. In a HTML web resource you are free to manipulate the DOM (i.e. limiting input) without risking breaking anything in the form itself.

If you include the `ClientContext.js.aspx` in the web resource, you can then copy what's entered in the "fake" field to the "real" field (via `parent.Xrm`, remember to uncheck 'Prevent cross-frame scripting').

This has the benefit of *not* requiring tampering with the form's DOM, and an HTML page with a single input field shouldn't be that hard to implement.